# What is the easiest way to update a rails button_to after an ajax post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ujs

I have two button_to calls to feature a video. The button calls a featured action in my video controller.

In my controller

```
def featured
 video = Video.find(params[:id]) 
 video.nfeatured = params[:nfeatured]
 video.save
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :back }
  format.js
 end
end
```

In my view

```
<td class="featured">
<% if video.nfeatured == false %>
<%= button_to 'Feature', featured_network_video_path(network, video, 
:nfeatured => true), :remote => true, :class => :feature %>

 <% else %>
 <%= button_to 'Remove', featured_network_video_path(network, video,
 :nfeatured => false), :remote => true, :class => :unfeature  %>
<% end %>
</td>
```

What is the most unobtrusive way to change the button to 'Remove' after a successful ajax post? Everything else is working properly. I tried make a jQuery toggle call in a featured.js.erb file but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to do so:

```
<td class="featured">
<%= render :template => "videos/featured" %>
</td>
```

featured.html.erb:

```
<% if @video.nfeatured == false %>
  <%= button_to 'Feature', featured_network_video_path(@network, @video, 
  :nfeatured => true), :remote => true, :class => :feature %>

<% else %>
  <%= button_to 'Remove', featured_network_video_path(@network, @video,
  :nfeatured => false), :remote => true, :class => :unfeature  %>
<% end %>
```

featured.js.erb

```
$(".featured").html("<%= j(render :template => "videos/featured", :handlers => [:erb]) %>");
```

And yes, I think this is not the best way. I would like to see a more right solution.

edited:
For a loop this solution is not suitable. The second version:

```
<% unless video.nfeatured %>
  <%= button_to 'Feature', featured_network_video_path(network, video, 
  :nfeatured => true), :remote => true, :class => :feature %>
  <%= button_to 'Remove', featured_network_video_path(network, video,
  :nfeatured => false), :remote => true, :class => 'unfeature hidden'  %>
<% else %>
  <%= button_to 'Feature', featured_network_video_path(network, video, 
  :nfeatured => true), :remote => true, :class => 'feature hidden' %>
  <%= button_to 'Remove', featured_network_video_path(network, video,
  :nfeatured => false), :remote => true, :class => :unfeature  %>
<% end %>
```

in some a coffee file:

```
$('.featured').bind "ajax:success", ->
  $(this).toggle()
  $(this).closest('a').toggle()
```

I'm not sure about this code (it obviously needs refactor), but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Why don't you use `j` instead of `escape_javascript`? Aren't the former is simpler to remember?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer... I am getting 500 server errors on the callback. It successfully saves the action but does not render the views correctly. Any thoughts? I also had to pass in local variables since this render is inside of a block.

Comment: @jdoe, thanks, I just did not know it before) @Kyle C, sorry, I forgot that you must either pass local parameters, or use instance variables. I prefer the second solution. You have an error probably because you have not defined the variables `@network` and `@video` in `featured` action. See more logs errors, it helps a lot. I edited the answer.

Comment: Still no luck, I added network and video instance variables to the featured action. The render is being called in a for loop so I try pass in those variables to the render and get a ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep):
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:219 . THis is the loop being called <% for video in network.videos do %>

Comment: @Kyle C, I've updated the answer, a similar solution should work.

Comment: so I ended up going a little different route and passing locals also into my respond_to |format| format.js . The ajax call is successful the response is correct it just does not update the html text. If you have any ideas let me know but you have answered my original question .